# How do I check if a user is listening to Spotify?

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a Discord bot, and I want a command that shows a user's current Spotify track. I've tried using `if(mentionedMember.presence.activities.name === 'Spotify')` but that doesn't seem to work, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First (this is what took me forever to figure out and is the most important), you need to enable the `GuildPresences` intent when creating your client.

Second, `guildMember.presence` itself can be null if the user isn't playing anything at all, so your code would throw an error when trying to read `presence.activities`.

Third, `presence.activities` is an array, so you need to loop through the array and search for an activity with the name of "Spotify".

Example:

```js
if (!mentionedMember.presence) return;

var spotifyActivity = mentionedMember.presence.activities.find(a => a.name === "Spotify");
if (spotifyActivity) {
    // execute your code here
}
```